# WPF custom effect animation programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, shader, hlsl

I try to use pixel shader effect animation programmatically in `WPF`, but below code uses a lot of CPU power.
Is there other method?

■Call Method
Setting effect while doing sequence.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"WateryEffect.ps");
    var uri = new Uri(path);
    WpfEffect wpfeffect = new WpfEffect(uri);

    BitmapImage img1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"3a28168e68.jpg")));
    ImageBrush imgbrush1 = new ImageBrush(img1);
    wpfeffect.input1 = imgbrush1;

    VisualBrush vbrush = new VisualBrush(text1);
    wpfeffect.input1 = vbrush;

    BitmapImage img2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"e98f58fa-2e58-4d38-9949-f3f40b6a2b13_7.jpg")));
    ImageBrush imgbrush2 = new ImageBrush(img2);
    wpfeffect.input2 = imgbrush2;

    double i = 1;
    do
    {
        wpfeffect.para0 = i;

        image1.Effect = wpfeffect;
        image2.Effect = wpfeffect;
        image3.Effect = wpfeffect;
        image4.Effect = wpfeffect;
        DoEvents();
        i = i - 0.0001;

    } while (i > -1);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a loop for this goes against the whole advantage of WPF. You need to run this effect update as a DoubleAnimation. I don't have your .ps file but I'm assuming that para01 is a DependencyProperty.

Try this code:

```
DoubleAnimation da = 
new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0,0,1)); // adjust as needed

(image1.Effect as WpfEffect).BeginAnimation(WpfEffect.para01Property, da);
(image2.Effect as WpfEffect).BeginAnimation(WpfEffect.para01Property, da);
(image3.Effect as WpfEffect).BeginAnimation(WpfEffect.para01Property, da);
(image4.Effect as WpfEffect).BeginAnimation(WpfEffect.para01Property, da);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I try this and doing well.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if the solutions works. Thanks. :)

Comment: wow been searching for 3 days now. Tinkering about 1000 lines of nonsense and couldn't get my animation to work. Thanks so much for this awesome 1-liner.